# Can I use just two relays to switch between two 3-phase brushless motors sharing the same driver?

Tags: motor, relay, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, three-phase

I have a 36V DC 3A (max) 3-phase brushless motor with it's own driver. I have a spare motor and I want to leave both motors connected to the same driver all the time, but only one motor will ever be used at a time. So they'll never be turned on at the same time...

I have a two-relay opto isolated module, and I'd like to know if my idea would work.

I want to switch between motors with just these two relays. I know three separate relays or a 3P2T relay would work, but I'd like to know if only 2 relays would also work.

This is my idea:

I would wire one phase of the driver, let's say, Phase A, to both motors permanently, and then:

Phase B from the driver to the Common of Relay 1

Phase C from the driver to the Common of Relay 2

Then I would wire Phase B from Motor 1 to the NC of Relay 1, and Phase B from Motor 2 to the NO of Relay 1

And finally I would wire Phase C from Motor 1 to the NC of Relay 2, and Phase C from Motor 2 to the NO of Relay 2

This 2-relay module I'm using is opto-isolated and is active LOW, so, when I put a low signal on the control pin, the relay(s) are turned on.

So, when the relays are not energized, motor 1 (which is in the NC position of relays B and C, and have phase A from the driver connected all the time, would be fully connected to the driver and work, and motor 2 would have phase A connected to the driver, but the other phases wouldn't be connected to anything, and the motor wouldn't have any current flowing through it, so motor 2 wouldn't work.

And when the relays are energized, motor 2 (which is in the NO position of relays 1 and 2, and phase A connected all the time , would be fully connected and work, and motor 1 would have only phase A connected to the driver, as the relays would disconnect it from phases B and C of the driver, so no current would flow in motor 1.

Does it all makes sense? Is my idea correct? Would it work?

Thanks!

Comment: are you saying that each motor has only a three wire harness?

Comment: @jsotola yes! Only three wires (A, B and C)

Comment: then your idea should work ... just a wild guess, the motor that has two windings disconnected may act as an antenna and radiate some RF interference

Comment: @jsotola what effects would this interference cause?? Would this be a "big" interference or of  small range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should work.

Here's the schematic.

[image]

However the conventional method is to use a single 3PDT latch relay as shown below.

[image]

The latch relay ensures that the selection is maintained even after power off.

Comment: Hi! Yes... Three poles relay would definitely work... But would the concept of using two separate single pole relays and leaving one phase always connected work either, as I asked?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, Your concept should work. My answer has been duly edited.